# Android app not showing in home screen but only in settings

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

Hey there so as the title says my app launcher is not showing in the home screen but my app is in the setting -> applications.

I think the problem is the manifest. I've been reading a lot of posts but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

I'm kinda new to Android mobile build so maybe some of you could see what's wrong in my manifest : [mymanifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf0EW.png)

EDIT - I finally found what was wrong, I was using the Oculus asset which I guess made some conflicts, it worked as soon as I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

it's look like you haven't add your application package in android manifest.

```
<manifest package="com.unity3d.player" ... >
    <application ... >
        <activity android:name=".UnityPlayerActivity" ... >
            ...
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

the application package is required for Android to identify your application. please read more in the android documentation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro

Comment: I tried adding my package and did read the documentation you provided but it still doesn't work. (I should probably mention that this a side load application for testing). I did more researches though. Tweeked my manifest with the help of others' manifest but no good results. I'll keep searching :)